# Группировка по string значениям

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate

есть таблица

| USER_ID | USLUGA_ID | STATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 453542 | 1 | unplanned |
| 453542 | 2 | unplanned |
| 453542 | 8 | unplanned |
| 6763451 | 1 | unplanned |
| 6763451 | 2 | connected |
| 34231 | 1 | connected |
| 34231 | 2 | connected |
| 34231 | 8 | unplanned |

Из нее необходимо сделать таблицу следующего вида

| USER_ID | USLUGA_1 | USLUGA_2 | USLUGA_8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 453542 | unplanned | unplanned | unplanned |
| 6763451 | unplanned | connected | NULL |
| 34231 | connected | connected | unplanned |

Делаю следующим образом

```
select ao.USER_ID,
       case
           when ao.USLUGA_ID = 1 then o.STATE
       end USLUGA_1,

       case
            when ao.USLUGA_ID = 2 then o.STATE
        end USLUGA_2,

        case
            when ao.USLUGA_ID = 8 then o.STATE
        end USLUGA_8

from REGSYSREF.ACTIVE_ORDERS ao -- активная заявка
         join REGSYSREF.ORDERS o
              on ao.USER_ID = o.USER_ID and ao.ORDER_ID = o.ID
where EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM a_dba.m_app_login_hist m
     WHERE m.user_id = ao.user_id
       AND m.login_date > add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -6))
  and NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
     FROM A_DBA.HB_PERIODIC_CHARGES hpc
     WHERE hpc.CHARGE_TYPE_ID = 121
       AND hpc.CHARGE_ETIME > sysdate
       AND hpc.USER_ID = ao.USER_ID)
order by USER_ID;
```

Но результат получается немного не то

| USER_ID | USLUGA_1 | USLUGA_2 | USLUGA_8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 453542 | unplanned | NULL | NULL |
| 453542 | NULL | unplanned | NULL |
| 453542 | NULL | NULL | unplanned |

Не понимаю как сгруппировать по строкам, что бы вся информация по пользователю была в одну строку

Comment: Эммм... а группировка-то где?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT user_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN usluga_id = 1 THEN state END) usluga_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN usluga_id = 2 THEN state END) usluga_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN usluga_id = 8 THEN state END) usluga_8
FROM {datasource}
-- WHERE {conditions}
GROUP BY user_id
```

Запрос (да и сама задача) предполагают, что `(user_id, usluga_id)` является уникальным.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал следующим образом через LISTAGG

```
select USER_ID,
         LISTAGG(USLUGA_1, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY USLUGA_1),
         LISTAGG(USLUGA_2, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY USLUGA_2),
         LISTAGG(USLUGA_8, ';') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY USLUGA_8)
      from (select ao.USER_ID,
                   case
                       when ao.USLUGA_ID = 1 then o.STATE
                       end USLUGA_1,

                   case
                       when ao.USLUGA_ID = 2 then o.STATE
                       end USLUGA_2,

                   case
                       when ao.USLUGA_ID = 8 then o.STATE
                       end USLUGA_8
            from REGSYSREF.ACTIVE_ORDERS ao -- активная заявка
                     join REGSYSREF.ORDERS o
                          on ao.USER_ID = o.USER_ID and ao.ORDER_ID = o.ID
            where EXISTS
                (SELECT 1
                 FROM a_dba.m_app_login_hist m
                 WHERE m.user_id = ao.user_id
                   AND m.login_date > add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -6))
              and NOT EXISTS
                (SELECT 1
                 FROM A_DBA.HB_PERIODIC_CHARGES hpc
                 WHERE hpc.CHARGE_TYPE_ID = 121
                   AND hpc.CHARGE_ETIME > sysdate
                   AND hpc.USER_ID = ao.USER_ID)
            order by USER_ID)
group by USER_ID;
```